# War with remotely piloted micro-machines

Tags: story-identification, warfare, nanotechnology

While waiting to get onto a computer booked at the local library about 2 years ago, I picked up a sci-fi novel whose name and author I cannot recall and began reading.

Elements of the opening part of the book that I can recall.

- A small squadron is trying to penetrate the defenses of an enemy power.
- It is mentioned they are traveling at an altitude of NN ***mm*** (which seemed odd at the time)
- They are swamped by autonomous flying defenders that hone in on the approaching craft and attack them (mostly by physically disassembling them in-flight).
- The pilots have a conversation in which it is revealed that this is not the first time they've attacked, and the defenses have improved over time.
- As each of the attacking craft are swamped the situation becomes more hopeless, until the last of the attackers is destroyed.
- It then turns out the pilots of the attack vehicles were at a far distant point, remotely operating micro/nano-machines..

That was mostly in the first chapter, as far as I read.  I'd guess it was written within the last 10 years (15 at the outside).

Can anyone identify this book & author?

Comment: I can almost recall it, it was a war game.  Seems like they were training for something.  I just have glimpse of the scenes, and I don't recall anything significant afterwords.  Maybe it was a short story?

Comment: @JamesJenkins  My recollection was that it was a novel and there was no 'practice' about it, but if you can recall the name of that story, please drop it in as I might be mistaken.

Comment: Interesting question! (My 2,000th vote btw)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like the 1st book of the Succession Series "The Risen Empire" by Scott Westerfield.  The opening chapter called Pilot fits what you have described.

Below is a brief SPOILER ALERT excerpt explaining your remembering NN mm:

> Marx checked the altimeter's last reading: 174 centimeters. At that height, the craft
> would take at least a minute before they hit the ground. Even with its sensor array
> furled and main rotor stalled, in a normal-density atmosphere an intelligence craft
> fell no faster than a speck of dust.
> Indeed, the Intelligencers were not much larger than specks of dust, and were
> somewhat lighter. With a wingspan of a single millimeter, they were very small craft
> indeed.
>
> Master Pilot Jocim Marx, Imperial Naval Intelligence, had flown microships for
> eleven years. He was the best.

[The Risen Empire Description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Risen_Empire)

Comment: Yes that definitely seems to be the one, barring my mistake with the dimensions.  I was almost going to mention a 'monarchy' but that detail was only vaguely formed in my mind..  Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Explains the 'NN _mm_' altitude-measuring units.